# How to add filter parameters to controllers in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add some parameters to a filter in Laravel framework.
The catch is, that i am calling my filters from controller's constructor and not route.

My code look like this:

**Controller**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->filter('before','test');
}
```

**Filter**

```
Route::filter('test',function(){
    // echo parameters passed to filter in controller.
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone else, it's quite simple..

**Controller**

```
$this->filter('before','test',array('value'));
```

**Filter**

```
Route::filter('test',function($label){
    echo $label; // Outputs the 'value'
});
```

Comment: As a shortcut, you can also write `$this->beforeFilter('test', array('value'))`.