# Laravel filter with parameter in construct

Tags: php, laravel

I searched on Stack and see this question [How to add filter parameters to controllers in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188040/how-to-add-filter-parameters-to-controllers-in-laravel).

I have a similar question but this time, I need to pass an flexible $myparam argument, the code looks like bellow:

In Route.php

```
Route::filter('diffauthor',function($myparam){
    if(Authority::cannot('edit', 'postedit', $myparam))
                        return View::make('permdeny.index');
});
```

and in Controller:

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->filter('before','diffauthor', $myparam);
    }
```

How do I pass $myparam base on user request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass parameters to filters as strings:

```
$this->filter('before', 'diffauthor:param1,param2');
```

Sometimes to get around this limitation I use the Session class as a sort of temporary store, or even inspect variables that are being passed to the method by looking at the object returned by `Request::route()` within my filter.